# AJAX request progress percentage log

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, request

I read content from
http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/ and i try make that ajax progress bar on my own site, but in console i have only xhr response when php script is full completed.

My part of JS code:

```
    $('#userSaveData').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var route = $form.attr('action');
        var form_data = $form.serializeObject();
        $.ajax({
        xhr: function()
        {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                //Upload progress
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        //Do something with upload progress
                        console.log(percentComplete);
                    }
                }, false);
                //Download progress
                xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        //Do something with download progress
                        console.log(percentComplete);
                    }
                }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        type: 'post',
        url: route,//url to my script below
        data: form_data, //some data, not used in script below
        success: function(){
            console.log('completed');
         }
        });
    return false;
   });
```

For example, part of my test php script is:

```
<?php
    usleep(10000000);
    echo true;
?>
```

My current console log first show 1, and then after about 10sec console.log write 'completed'

Simply, i want while ajax request is in progress (php usleep time is about 10sec) display in console percentage of ajax reqest (is that possible?).

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be with the server side, since the client seems correct. That long call to `usleep()` may freeze server output, and if the client doesn't receive the HTTP response status line, it can't even fire the `start` event on the XHR object (for example the service may respond with a 404 status code, which is an error at the protocol level and is reported as delivering failure).

Also, the browser may need to accumulate a certain number of bytes before passing the event to the JS engine. I used the following script on the server side to send a 4KB load of data N times (4096 octets seems enough for Chrome at least to update the progress counter):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Length: " . ($size * $times));
flush();
ob_flush(); 

$size = 4096;
$times = 5;

function send($size) {
  while($size-- > 0) {
    echo "A";
  }
  echo "\n";
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) {
  send($size);
  flush();
  ob_flush(); 
  sleep(1);
}
```

This is the script on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        console.log(evt.loaded);
                    }
                }, false);
            return xhr;
        }
        , type: 'post'
        , cache: false
        , url: "sleep.php"});
```

Comment: I try that, but same result.

Comment: @user1477508 can you better describe the problem? Do you see any JS error in the console? Can you set a breakpoint in the progress callback? And how can the browser know `evt.total` if your server script doesn't send any `Content-Length` header?

Comment: No errors in console, server script is as above, lease describe what i need to add..

Comment: Please, set a breakpoint in the progress listener and tell what the value for `evt.total` is.

Comment: First, in xhr.upload listeneru event.total is 198, then in second xhr listeneru event.total is 0

Comment: What if you try with the updated script in my answer?

Comment: Then in second xhr listeneru event.total is 10

Comment: And is the progress listener called 10 times?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38831/discussion-between-raffaele-and-user1477508)